# Count in numerical order only in blank (empty) cells

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to use VBA to auto fill (1, 2, 3, ....) in column "A" while skipping rows that are not blank/empty. For example, if there is text/data in "A3" and "A5", the code would count as follows:

```
"A1" = 1              "B1" = text/data
"A2" = 2              "B2" = text/data
"A3" = text/data      "B3" = text/data
"A4" = 3              "B4" = text/data
"A5" = text/data      "B5" = text/data
"A6" = 4              "B6" = text/data
"A7" = 5              "B7" = text/data
```

...and so on

So far I've only been able to skip the rows with previously entered text but that count continues as if it wasn't skipping any cells.

Please Note: I'm using `.End(xlDown).Count` in column "B" to define how far down the counter should go.

This is what I have so far

```
Sub Counter()

Dim NoF As Long
Dim Test As Long

NoF = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Count

For i = 1 To NoF

    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = i
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Offset(i + 1, 1).Select
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a second variable which counts the rows with text. Initialize it outside of the for loop to zero and add 1 if there was some text. Next, you just need to subtract it from i.

```
j = 0
For i = 1 To NoF

    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = i - j
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Offset(i + 1, 1).Select
        j = j + 1
    End If

Next i
```

---

You do not need to `Offset`, this works as well

```
Option Explicit

Sub Counter()

Dim NoF As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long

NoF = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Count
j = 0

For i = 1 To NoF

    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = i - j
    Else
        j = j + 1
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Capema00 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. The same goes for upvoting.